# Sorting NSMutableArray contains NSMutableString in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutablestring

Newbie Question,

I am playing with NSMutableArray *myBook that contains  card elements (name and email address).

I want myBook displayed with descending list.

AddressBook.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AddressCard.h"
@interface AddressBook : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *bookName;

@property (nonatomic , strong) NSMutableArray *book;
```

AddressCard.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AddressCard : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *name, *email;
```

AddressBook.m

```
- (void) sort{
    [book sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareNames:)];
}

- (void) showList{

    NSLog(@"====== Contents of: %@ =======",bookName);


    for (AddressCard *theCard in book) {
        NSLog(@"%-20s    %-32s", [theCard.name UTF8String], [theCard.email UTF8String] );
    }

    NSLog(@"===============================");
}
```

AddressCard.m

```
- (NSComparisonResult) compareNames: (id) element{


    return [name compare:[element name]];
}
```

my CompareNames method returns Ascending result. How do I make it to return Descending?

Thanks !

Comment: Try `return [self.name compare:[element name]];`.

Comment: @rmaddy it didn't work.

Comment: Ah, based on the accepted answer I misunderstood your question. Your sort was working just in the opposite order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while `- (void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator` method suppose to sorts the array's elements in ascending order, the comparator method should return `NSOrderedAscending` if the array is smaller than the argument, `NSOrderedDescending` if the array is larger than the argument, and `NSOrderedSame` if they are equal.

Since the NSComparisonResult define as:

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending
};

typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```

All you need is a descendingComparator, something like:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareNameInDesendingOrder:(AddressCard *)aCard {
    return -[self.name compare:[aCard name]];
}

- (void)sortInDesendingOrder {
    [book sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareNameInDesendingOrder:)];
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Or reverse the compare: `return [aCard.name compare:self.name];`.

Comment: @lancy I changed method compareNames: to take (AddressCard *) aCard as arguments, and it worked. is this really acceptable than using (id) element as argument?

Comment: @user3213703 , id work fine, I just like the static type checking.